# How can we provide username and password of the external git repository while importing it in kie workbench 7.4

Tags: jboss, kie, drools-kie-server

I am using Kie workbench 7.4. While importing an external git repository, it is asking only the repository URL. Not the username and password. So while clicking on the next button, authentication is failing.

I am getting "Unable to complete your request. The following exception occurred: java.lang.RuntimeException: URL not authorized."

This is the Kie workbench UI.[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLpc5.png)

I am using Wildfly 10 as the server.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is captured in [jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-6468) . For now you can clone git repository into file system using git clone command and then clone it into kie-workbench.

Comment: Thank You for the answer.
Can you please tell me how to clone it to kie-workbench.